# How do I troubleshoot "INSERT INTO"?

Tags: php, sql

I have just now solved an issue that was preventing my SQL "INSERT INTO" code from executing, but it took a long time to find. A comma was missing somewhere.

Suppose this happens to me again. Perhaps I forget a comma again, or perhaps it's some other issue. Is there a diagnostic function I can run that will help me pinpoint what went wrong?

I already know about `mysqli_error($conn)` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)` but they didn't help at all.

Comment: If `mysqli_error` didn't help then you either not using mysqli or doing it wrong.

Comment: If you're executing a `mysqli_query(...)` which results in an error, `mysqli_error($conn)` is *exactly* how you'd get that error.  How does that "not help at all"?

Comment: You can always write your SQL queries in something like mysqlworkbench first to make sure they work before putting them in code.

Comment: @David I feel like the biggest moron in the history of ever. I forgot to type "echo" before "mysqli_query()". I fixed that just now and it's working great.

Comment: It depends entirely on which error message you are getting. What error are you getting? Are you getting an error message at all?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, it was a really basic error. I wrote `mysqli_error($conn);` when I should have written `echo mysqli_error($conn);`